# R sum a twice nested list using purrr

Tags: r, dplyr, sum, purrr

I have a data.frame with the following dimensions:
**Output:**
    `as_tibble(data2)`

```
lamda meanlog sdlog freq      freqsev   
<dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <list>    <list>    
1     5       9   2   <int [4]> <list [4]>
2     2      10   2.1 <int [4]> <list [4]>
3     3      11   2.2 <int [4]> <list [4]>
```

where `freqsev` is a list of values of length `freq`, and `freq` itself is a list of values of length `s`, where `s` is the number of simulations.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
s <- 5
data <- data.frame(lamda = c(5, 2, 3), meanlog = c(9, 10, 11), sdlog = c(2, 2.1, 2.2))

data2 <- data %>% mutate(
  freq = map(lamda, ~rpois(s, .x)),
  freqsev = map(freq, ~map(.x, function(k) rlnorm(k, meanlog, sdlog)))
  )
```

I would like to sum `freqsev` (producing `<dbl [4]>` where the [4] is the index of `s`) i.e. a sum over the number of `freq` occurrences e.g.

For `data2$freqsev[[1]][[1]]` I would expect the sum.

How can this be achieved? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe `lapply(data2$freqsev, function(x) vapply(x,sum,1))`.

Comment: Is this any different from your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54471512/purrr-apply-functions-to-lists-in-data-frame-over-specifed-dimensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, this is a really complicated way of storing your data and you would probably be better off using `unnest()` after creating the `freq` column. However, you can get the sums of the `freqsev` vectors like this:

```
data2 <- data %>% mutate(
  freq = map(lamda, ~rpois(s, .x)),
  freqsev = map(freq, ~map(.x, function(k) rlnorm(k, meanlog, sdlog))),
  freqsum = map(freqsev, ~map_dbl(.x, ~sum(.x)))
)
```

Because `freqsev` is a double-nested list, you also need to double-map the sum operation.

Comment: Thanks @(A. Stam) that sums as expected, however it returns another <list> with a vector of length 1 - how can I get rid of this and return a <dbl>? I'll look into the unnest() function

Comment: There is a beautiful way to do that in `purrr`, using `map_dbl` instead of `map` (or `map_chr`, etc). I edited my answer to use the `map_dbl` function.